# How to color manage sddm login screen?

Tags: color-management, sddm

I'm using Kubuntu with sddm login screen. Currently, the monitor icc profile loads after login. I've tried "Install System Wide" in the colord system setting, but that appears to only make the profile available for use by other users. How can I apply the icc profile to the login screen?

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 has three options in *System Settings > Startup & Shutdown > Autostart > Run on: `Startup*, `Logout`, and `Before session startup`. The last option possibly maybe of interest.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtumP.png but maybe that option only appears for scripts and not for Desktop files.

Comment: I don't use Wayland at all (which isn't really ready for Kubuntu end-users), nor do I have any direct experience of running scripts before login. Also, I don't know anything about color profiles. I have just two scripts, one for Conky and one for Dropbox, and both essentially just delay running them for a minutes *after* login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still using X11, as I am, you can try the following:

1. Copy the `icc` file to a path without any spaces.
2. Decide on a terminal command that will load the `icc` file. There are several options. This is the one I chose:

   ```
   /usr/bin/dispwin /var/lib/colord/icc/startup.icc
   ```
3. Add the command to load the icc profile to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`. This file may be overwritten when the system is updated.

   **or** ... create your own startup script, and add the following to `/etc/sddm.conf`.

   ```
   [X11]
   DisplayCommand="/path/to/startup_script"
   ```

**References**

- ArchWiki: [ICC profiles](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ICC_profiles)
- Ubuntu Manpage: [sddm.conf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man5/sddm.conf.5.html)